# What is the difference between someString += "a" vs someString += 'a' in python

Tags: python, string, char

I understand that "a" adds a string of value (a) to someString, and 'a' adds a char of value (a) to someString, but is there a difference in time/space between the two? since they only take up the space of a single char wouldn't this be the same in essence? Is there a preferred method?

Answer (score 2):

You are incorrect.  What you are saying comes from C.  There is absolutely no difference in Python between single quotes and double quotes.  None at all.  Python does not have a "char" type.  They're just one-character strings.